# view compresses on low dimension devices and stretches on high dimensions autolayout ios

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I am using custom button. Set constraints as shown in images.
[image]

But when I run in on simulator view compresses on low dimension devices and stretches on high dimensions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your constraints show **Proportional** Width and Height, so yes, you have told auto-layout to make the button smaller on low dimension devices and larger on high dimension devices.

Comment: yes right but why it is stretching and compressing? Am I mistaking somewhere?

Comment: If you have your button constrained to 80% of the width of the view, it will be "narrow" on an iPhone SE, wider on an iPhone 8, much wider on an iPhone rotated to landscape orientation, and really really wide on an iPad Pro... because it will always stretch to 80% of the width. If that's not what you're talking about, then you need to edit your question and include a better description of what you mean by *"stretching and compressing"* ... maybe include a couple images of what you're seeing as well.